# @RestController over interface + spring

Tags: spring-boot, java-11

I accidentally found this technique of using RestController annotation.
(I saw this not on the internet, but in one of the examples that I was shown. I couldn't find it on the internet)

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/user/point")
public interface ExampleRestController {


    @PostMapping("{key}" )
    @Operation(summary = "Manage...", 
            description = "Allow user ...")
    public HttpStatus changePoints(
            @PathVariable 
            @NotBlank 
            @Parameter(description = "Id user") String key,
            @RequestParam("point") 
            @Min(0) @Parameter(description = "count something..", required = true) Long point,
            @RequestParam("type") 
            @Parameter(description = "Type of...", required = true) TypeOperation type

    );
}
```

What is this technique, who knows ?

I've seen the Rest Api just like this. Can Spring also dynamically create an endpoint method in the RestController, as it does when executing ...extend CrudRepository ? And how does AOP work in this case ? After all, in order for the bean to be configured, we need to put the annotation above the class (like how it is done at the service level), if you put it above the interface, the full automatic configuration of the bean is not guaranteed

Comment: Following is a good place to start : [Spring Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I didn't ask you how to do this, and I know where the documentation is, and I didn't ask you how to do the same, read the question ....

Comment: @skhyho I am not the the downvoter.I re-read your question and still thinks my first comment is valid. Your question is not specific to a topic . Probably you need to break down your question to a specific issue that you are facing or a concept that you are not able to comprehend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is  **spring-interface-driven-controllers**.
This is new feature of Spring MVC. ( starting with Spring 5.1)